# How does one use dune to create a js_of_ocaml library?

Tags: ocaml, js-of-ocaml

I'm wondering what a `dune` file looks like for a library (rather than an executable) which compiles to `js_of_ocaml` and why is it recommended to use an executable instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything particular for libraries to make them compatible with js_of_ocaml: js_of_ocaml works on the final executable bytecode, regardless of the libraries.

That being said, if you want to use js-specific things, js_of_ocaml is also an ocaml library that you can just depends on and which will contain bindings to various javascript functions.

```
(library
  (name my_library)
  (public_name my_library)
  (libraries (js_of_ocaml))
)
```

For building js files, you should use the executable stanza (as per the dune docs).

Comment: Okay, this helped, thanks. I guess in the docs the recommendation for exe is for building a final js file.